# embed-responsive shows white border in bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have a webpage, that shows another `html` page using `iframe`. Please see my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DotWifi</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxpage?xxxId=123&tok=$tok&authaction=$authtarget"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am try to show a responsive webpage using `iframe` using `embed-responsive-item` class. But it shows a white border in bottom. Please see the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a border, it's simply the background of the body.

The iframe's parent div, `embed-responsive-4by3` is supposed to have a width to height ratio of 4 by 3. That's what this class does! So if the width is 416 pixels (the width of the window) then the height becomes 312 pixels.
That's all there is to it.

If you don't want that, the solution is to remove the `embed-responsive-4by3` class from the div.

Or, if all your page ever does is show another page in an iframe, you can dispense with Bootstrap altogether and put only the iframe on the page!